# How to pick Memo and Calendar in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm working a project that is similar to Message in Android.
But I don't know how to pick Memo and calendar like them.
I try to Google but there's nothing matching what I want.
Thanks.

Comment: heard about content providers just search for content provider for calender and memmo

Comment: @droidhot Android doesn't support Action_PICK for these, does it?

Comment: i am not sure on that but u will get content provider which contains the data of entries - use it for best outcome as you wish

Comment: Thank you @droidhot , but I don't have time for getting content provider as well as creating custom GUI.., In my opinion, Message in android use Action_pick for doing these. That's the fastest way, I suppose.